# unknown attribute `user_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to associate my users that I created with Devise to the posts  . But I am getting the error mentioned int the title whenever I try to create a post logged in as a user. Thank you very much :)

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:task))
    @post.user = current_user
    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post, alert:"Post created successfully."
    else
        redirect_to new_post_path, alert: "Error creating post."
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :posts
end
```

Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_presence_of :task
belongs_to :user

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have a `user_id` column on your Posts table in your db.

Answer (score 3):

For adding user id to pin the following worked for me

```
rails g migration add_user_to_pin user_id:integer
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into you **schema.rb** and under **post**  table can you seen
the **user_id** column. If there is no **user_id** you need to add a migration column to add **user_id** using the following command:

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id: integer
```

Using this command a migration file name **20171220171727_add_user_id_to_posts.rb** will be created. For you the time stamp 20141220171727 will be different. In the migration file you will see you have the following code:

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :posts, 'user_id', :integer
  end
end
```

If your migration looks like the above then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

to apply the migration. Restart the server now and see if your code works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you want to add an index that corresponds to an association you havo to create a migration using, in this case:

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToPin user:references
```

Rails will immediately know that you want to include an index onto the second table using the User Id unique, primary, key.

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

In your create action, try something like:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:task))
  @post.user_id = current_user.id
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, alert:"Post created successfully."
  else
    redirect_to new_post_path, alert: "Error creating post."
  end
end
```

and also make sure in your Posts database table that you have an integer field called **user_id**

Answer (score 0):

I just did this same stuff.  Mine works this way for me.

I do have a user_id column in my posts table.  I verified by doing this in rails console (rails c)

```
Post.column_names
```

Which returned all the fields, and user_id was among them.

in my Post model it belongs_to :user, and in my User model it has_many :posts.

In my PostsController though, mine differs from yours.

I have

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.user_id = current_user.id
```

Which seems to work just fine.  This was also written after I implemented Devise for the user